# How can I get version of release before updating application?

Tags: android

I am beginner in android programming, so please help me to find out in some questions and sorry for my English. I develop application on eclipse for android. And I want to develop module of load update file from website. I know how can I get update file, load and launch it from programm code (example of code you can see by this link [Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)). But before I want to get version of release of update file. And I don't know how I can do it. May be somebody developed the same module and can give me advise.

Comment: Are you trying to find the version of the app in a downloaded APK file or the version of your currently running app?

Comment: I am trying to find  the version of the app in a downloaded APK file

Comment: PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.package.name.of.your.app", 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;

Comment: @EugenePinchuk That's not what the OP is asking.  He needs to get version information from an APK file, not from an installed app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PackageManager` for this purpose.  I have successfully used this code in my app:

```
PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
if(info != null) {
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = info.applicationInfo;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        appInfo.sourceDir = apkPath;
        appInfo.publicSourceDir = apkPath;
    }       
    String version = info.versionName;
    int vcode = info.versionCode;
}
```